# Optimal db schema and query statement for sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, database-schema

I am looking for an optimal db schema for the following problem in sqlite:

I have players and teams, with players assigned to teams (one player can belong to several teams) and I need to be able to find the team with the specified players passed as arguments. For example, if team 2 has players 1, 3 and 4 then if I query players 1, 3 and 4 I need to get team 2.

Also, it would be useful to query a team and get the list of players in it.

At the moment the schema I have is:

```
players: id(PK), name
teams: id(PK), name
players_in_teams: player_id(FK), team_id(FK)
```

But I doubt this is the best solution and therefore need help.

Comment: *"one player can belong to several teams"* . . . At the same time?

Comment: What you've created is a many-to-many table, and if indeed a player can belong to several teams (and a team can have more than one member), then that is the correct schema.

Comment: Your schema is fine, that's exactly how you should do it. To find what team(s) a player is on you would do: `SELECT team_id FROM players_in_teams WHERE player_id = MYID`.

Comment: `select distinct team_id from players_in_teams where player_id in (1, 3, 4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema is fine. Having a "junction" or "link" table in the middle is the standard of modeling a many-to-many relationship.

You just need to consider index design of the junction table to best support both "directions" of querying (that you have indicated you need).

- The query: "for given players, find teams" can be satisfied by index on `{player_id, team_id}`.
- The query: "for given team(s), find players" can be satisfied by index on `{team_id, player_id}`.

In other words, you'll need two composite indexes on same fields, but with different field order. One of the indexes, you have probably already implicitly created (when you created the primary key), so you just need to explicitly create the remaining index.